# Is "in about" grammatical in "I'll reach there in about 5 minutes"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, adverbs

Is it correct to say "I'll reach there in about 5 minutes?"  Is "in about" correct in this sentence?

Comment: Native speakers are more likely to say: "I'll get there ... " or "I'll be there ... " than "I'll reach there ... ".

Comment: @Shoe +1 That's right, and you beat me to it!

Comment: Take out "about" and you get "I'll reach there in 5 minutes".  Perfectly correct (though, as stated elsewhere, "I'll get there ..." or "I'll be there ..." would be more idiomatic).  Add "about" to indicate that the 5 minutes is approximate.  Still perfectly correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly fine. I suspect you might be confused because you are seeing "in about" as a linkage of two contradictory prepositions, meaning something like "inside outside." But those aren't the meanings here. See it this way instead: "in" is used to indicate a period of time ("5 minutes"), and "about" in this case means "approximately." So the sentence is, "The period of time it will take me to reach there will be approximately 5 minutes."

Comment: Yes, _about_ modifies _five minutes_ and is a quantifier modifier here rather than a preposition. Good sleuthing, John - I hadn't thought of the '_contradictory_ prepositions' false trail.

Comment: Yes, the intended parse is the normal right-branching **[in [about [five minutes]]]**, rather than the much less common structure **[[in about] [five minutes]]**. The most important thing in grammar is to recognize ***Constituents***, because grammatical rules apply **only** to constituents.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, Edwin!I appreciate the compliment.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, John. I have to say, I am genuinely delighted to have assent from you at any time, because your knowledge of this field is astounding and fascinating.